# User Inactivity, display screensaver using AppDelegate Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I need to detect user inactivity on all view controllers, by detecting all touches made. My current AppDelegate code is not detecting the touches made on `UIButton` and other UI controls. How do I detect all touches made, including `UIButtons`, `UILabels` and `UITextfields`? I have looked at many Stack Overflow articles but I cant seem to adapt it to my needs.  If this is not possible how do I extend my original `TimerUIApplication` class to the other views to detect touches made. Thanks in advance.

AppDegegate Code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{
    var window: UIWindow?
    static let ApplicationDidTimoutNotification = "AppTimout"

    // The timeout in seconds for when to fire the idle timer.
    let timeoutInSeconds: TimeInterval = 5

    var idleTimer: Timer?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        application.isIdleTimerDisabled = true

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let defaultValues = ["promotionIsEnabled_preference"  : "YES",
                             "promotionDuration_preference" : "10"]
        userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)
        userDefaults.synchronize()
        return true
    }



    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    print ("app started")
    self.resetIdleTimer()
     idleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeoutInSeconds, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.idleTimerExceeded), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    print("touched")
    self.resetIdleTimer()

}

// Resent the timer because there was user interaction.
func resetIdleTimer() {
    if let idleTimer = idleTimer {
        idleTimer.invalidate()
    }
}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.resetIdleTimer()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

     idleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeoutInSeconds, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.idleTimerExceeded), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

@objc func idleTimerExceeded() {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: TimerUIApplication.ApplicationDidTimoutNotification), object: nil)
    print ("Inactive User")
    let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainPromo") as UIViewController
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}


}
```

Original Code that I used in the AppDelegate.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class TimerUIApplication: UIApplication {
    static let ApplicationDidTimoutNotification = "AppTimout"

    // The timeout in seconds for when to fire the idle timer.
    let timeoutInSeconds: TimeInterval = 5

    var idleTimer: Timer?

    // Resent the timer because there was user interaction.
    func resetIdleTimer() {
        if let idleTimer = idleTimer {
            idleTimer.invalidate()
        }

        idleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeoutInSeconds, target: self, selector: #selector(TimerUIApplication.idleTimerExceeded), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    // If the timer reaches the limit as defined in timeoutInSeconds, post this notification.
    @objc func idleTimerExceeded() {

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: TimerUIApplication.ApplicationDidTimoutNotification), object: nil)
        print ("out")
    }


    override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {

        super.sendEvent(event)

        if idleTimer != nil {
            self.resetIdleTimer()
        }

        if let touches = event.allTouches {
            for touch in touches {
                if touch.phase == UITouchPhase.began {
                    self.resetIdleTimer()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes I am

Comment: Then you should be able to provide a custom `UIWindow` subclass that detects all touches via the `window` property of your app delegate. I'm afraid it is late where I am, but I will try and add an answer in the morning.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried adding a gestureRecogniser to the UIWindow within AppDeglegate. But it still does not pick up the touches within a UITextfieild or other components within a  view on my ViewController. Thank you, look forward to it!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 - Create a `CustomWindow` in your `AppDelegate.swift` which goes over your Storyboard Views, that registers touches, but does not cancel them. 
Code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

var topWindow: CustomWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        topWindow = CustomWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        topWindow?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        topWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal + 1
        topWindow?.isHidden = false
    }
```

Create a CustomWindow.swift class that recieves your actions and handles them. Code:

```
import UIKit

class CustomWindow: UIWindow{

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        // What you want to do in here.
        return false
    }
```